# `PFFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` block not getting called Obj-C

Tags: parse-platform, objective-c-blocks

I have the following code, to retrieve an image from Parse. This code block is in a recursive loop that gets called for a list of images in an array.

```
PFFile *remoteImageFile             =   object[@"Image"]
[remoteImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    DDLogInfo(@"%s:%d %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, [error debugDescription]);
    // other logics
}];
```

The code fetches most of the images successfully, the sizes of the images being 2MB to 3MB. But randomly it fails for certain files and the block is not getting fired and my whole fetching operation freezes. Couldn't find the reason.

Any help please

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that there is a bug in the Parse framework here. The most probable cause is that your `remoteImageFile` is nil which means that `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:` is not even called.
Can you check by using the following code :

```
PFFile *remoteImageFile = object[@"Image"];
if (remoteImageFile == nil || ![remoteImageFile isKindOfClass:[PFFile class]]) {
    NSLog(@"Error : remoteImageFile = %@", remoteImageFile);
} else {
    [remoteImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        DDLogInfo(@"%s:%d %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, [error debugDescription]);
        // other logics
    }];
}
```

Comment: Checking with your code from yesterday evening and the freeze is not happening :-) Surprise!

Comment: This should be the selected answer.